# Intersection of a domain $R$ with an ideal $\mathfrak a$ of height $2$ in $R[X]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and consider the polynomial ring $R[X]$ over $R$. Suppose that ${\mathfrak a}$ is an ideal of $R[X]$ such that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak a) = 2$.

Q. Is the intersection $R \cap \mathfrak a \neq 0$? That is, does the intersection $R \cap \mathfrak a$ contain an element other than $0$?

Either case of $R$ being noetherian or nonnoetherian should be answered in the affirmative. Still, I am not sure whether it is true or not when ${\mathfrak a}$ is not a prime.

Comment: Just go to the fraction field of $R$ to see that the intersection is zero, then the height is at most one.

Comment: "a nontrivial element other than zero" can be reformulated as "a nonzero element whose value is not zero, and which is also distinct from zero, excluding the possibility of being equal to zero".

Comment: @YCor I am afraid your rephrasing is not sufficiently complete

Comment: More seriously, essentially a rephrasing of Mohan's sentence: if $P\subset I$ is prime and $P\cap R=\{0\}$, then $R[X]_P$ is a localization of $\mathrm{Frac}(R)[X]$ and hence has Krull dimension $\le 1$, so $P$ has height $\le 1$. Hence $I$ has height $\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks, so by Ycor, the answer is in the affirmative for any ring R. Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Let R be Noetherian ring. if $R \cap \mathfrak{a}=0$,then $R \subset R[X]/\mathfrak{a}$ and hence $R^{\times} = R[X]^{\times} \subset (R[X]/\mathfrak{a})^{\times} $. Therefore $\dim R \leq \dim R[X]/\mathfrak{a} $ .
But this is contradiction since $\ht \mathfrak{a}=2$ and $\dim R[X]=\dim R +1$.

Comment: Without hypotheses on the ring $A=R[X]$, there is no relation between $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak{a}) $ and $\dim A/\mathfrak{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$. The technique of working over $K$ gives the affirmative answer regardless of whether $\mathfrak a$ is prime. My understanding is that the height of a prime ideal $P$ in a not necessarily noetherian ring is defined to be the length of a maximal chain of primes between $(0)$ and $P$. The height of a non-prime ideal is the minimal height of its minimal primes.

Assume that $\mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak a)=2$ and $\mathfrak a\cap R=(0)$, aiming for contradiction. Take a non-zero element $f\in\mathfrak a$. Let $f=f_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots f_r^{\alpha_r}$ be the factorization of $f$ into irreducible factors in $K[X]$. Then $P_i:=f_iK[X]\cap R[X]$ is a prime ideal of height 1. Hence $\mathfrak a\not\subset P_i$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,r\}$. Take an element $g\in\mathfrak a\setminus\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^rP_i$. Then $g$ is relatively prime to $f$ in $K[X]$. Take $a,b\in K[X]$ such that $af+bg=1$. Multiplying $af+bg$ by all the denominators of all the coefficients of $a$ and $b$ yields a non-zero element of $\mathfrak a\cap R$. Contradiction.